# Customizing Primary Menu to include custom taxonomy description

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, walker

I've a hard time implementing the custom primary menu behaviour.

I've already:

- Created a custom `post type: products` that has a custom
  `taxonomy: product_category` associated with it.
- Activated and implemented `Taxonomy Meta` plugin to have the possibility of adding a `category image` for the `product_category` taxonomies

The thing I want to achieve is:

- After manually inserting each `product_category` taxonomy under the `Product` page in primary menu editing page in admin side, instead of just showing the name of the taxonomy in the client side, I want the menu to *show the name, description and the image*

Now, I know there's is a description field in the menu editing page, but what I want is to have that description come from the taxonomy description. Just like the image.

**LT;DR**
How to customise the primary navigation to show taxonomy description (not the menu item description) next to it's name? How can I get access to that taxonomy description?

**Side note**
I've created a child theme of `Twenty Thirteen` but haven't touched any of it's functions or menu handling thing etc.